# How to create computed attribute in controller based on store information and model hasMany relationship

Tags: javascript, ember.js, promise

I have a model for a type of object "Module". Simplified, it is like this:

```
App.Module = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    orModules: DS.hasMany('module', { inverse: null }),  // reflexive relship
});
```

In the view of the `Module`, there should be a list of all `Module` records that are not the current `model`, and not contained in `model.orModules`. I think this information does not belong in the `App.Module` but in the `App.ModuleController`.

The problem is that I still haven't got my head around the promises and asynchronous stuff, and the "classes" in `Ember` and `DS` like `DS.PromiseArray`.

Good, this is my attempt:

```
App.ModuleController = Ember.Controller.extend({

    availableModules: function () {
        var thisModule = this.get('model');  
        var allModules = this.store.findAll('module');  // this is a promise, right?
        var orModules = thisModule.get('orModules');  // this as well, more exactly a `DS.PromiseArray`, right?

        return DS.PromiseArray.create({
            promise: Ember.RSVP.hash({allMods: allModules, orMods: orModules}, function (res) {
                // Here I guess both promises are fulfilled, so I 
                // have access to all data

                // But, first problem res.allMods and res.orMods have different interfaces. 
                // I can access res.allMods.content for the Module objects, and call mod.get('id'), but I have trouble transversing res.orMods.

                // And the second and big problem is, I don't know what should I return.
                // even returning some hardcoded value raises an exception 
                // "Assertion Failed: ArrayProxy expects an Array or Ember.ArrayProxy, but you passed object
                return [{id: 666, name: '666'}];
            })

        });

    }.property('model.orModules'),

});
```

So, as you can see I'm pretty confused. Any help? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should serve both current module and other modules from the route:

```
return Ember.RSVP.hash({
  modules:       allModulesPromise,
  currentModule: currentModulePromise
});
```

You can extract current module from modules, for example:

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model () {   
    let allModulesPromise = this.store.find('module');

    let currentModulePromise = allModulesPromise.then(
      // Whatever way you use to identify which module is the current
      modules => modules.findBy('id', '1')
    );

    return Ember.RSVP.hash({
      modules:       allModulesPromise,
      currentModule: currentModulePromise
    });
  }
});
```

With both `modules` and `currentModule` at hand, it becomes trivial to filter out other modules:

```
App.IndexController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  availableModules: Ember.computed(
    'model.currentModule.children.@each.id',
    'model.modules.@each.id',
    function() {
      let currentModule = this.get('model.currentModule');
      let children      = currentModule.get('children');

      return this
        .get('model.modules')
        .filter( module => (
          module !== currentModule
          && !children.contains(module)
        ));
    }
  )
});
```

Demo: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/woqofo/3/edit?html,js,output

#### Update in response to comments

When the `model` hook of a route returns a non-promise, the route immediately passes the returned value to the controller and the controller renders the template.

But when the `model` hook returns a promise, the route will enter the Loading state and wait for the promise to resolve. When it resolves with a certain value, *then* the route passes the value to the controller to render the template with.

As a result, you never have to deal with promises in the controller! You already have resolved data to render.

You can do Ajax requests in the controller, but why bother? Instead, you can use URL params and query params to reflect current model in the URL. If you do, the route will update the `model` property on the controller whenever the URL changes.

To fetch some arbitrary data that does not belong in the URL, use services.

TL/DR: avoid declaring promises (doing Ajax requests) in controllers/components and your life will be happier. :D

Comment: Wow, works! thank you very much. But home come? can't I access the store from the controller? is it allowed only from the router?

Comment: And another question... when you do `let currentModule = this.get(model.currentModule)`, it is still a promise, right? so how is it guaranteed that this promise is resolved inside of the `.filter` callback?